# Custom Feature Form - Add multiple Features - Crashes when commiting

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-plugins

I use a custom feature form to set new features for my point layer.
Beause i have to set many points i dont want to open the form new every time i set a new point.
Thats why i added a function which uses the same form to set multiple features.

Now it works when i dont reopen the form. But when i set new points, close the form, reopen it and set new points QGIS crashes. I figured out that the bun_layer.commitChanges() line is responsible. But i dont know what to do about it.

Here my current code:

```
new_point = pointTool.point
new_point = QgsPoint(new_point.x(), new_point.y())

# new Feat
feat_new = QgsFeature(bun_layer.fields())
feat_new.setGeometry(new_point)

if id_.text() not in ['NULL', '']: feat_new.setAttribute("id", id_.text())
if name.text() not in ['NULL', '']: feat_new.setAttribute("name", name.text())

if bun_layer.isEditable():
    bun_layer.commitChanges()

with edit(bun_layer):
   bun_layer.addFeature(feat_new)
```

i also tried this:

```
caps = bun_layer.dataProvider().capabilities()
if caps & QgsVectorDataProvider.AddFeatures:
    bun_layer.dataProvider().addFeature(feat_new)
```

With the result that i can set the points even the second time. But when i deactivate editing qgis chrashes again.

I tried some stuff to get debugg info, but since i use windows 10 it seems very difficult to get a crash report.